# update notification in notification shade

Tags: updates

Every time I turn on my PC, a message appears in the top line of the notification about the successful update of the system, this happens every time.

Tell me please, what is the reason for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vJ3w.jpg)

Comment: We can't read the non-english popup text. Please [edit] your Question and add an English translatoon.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].